# Detect language font supported in android device

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to test myanmar font in android devices. 
The below link is the concept of the different myanmar unicode and zawgyi. 
https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Myanmar%3A+Android+Zawgyi+and+Unicode

https://my.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Font

In general speaking, unicode is a standard to save/read for characters. After android 4.4, it supports Myanmar unicode in device. Zawgyi is a font but it is not unicode complaint. Zawgyi also has it's own keyboard for interpreting its font.

Unicode 0x104e character is  [image]

Zawgyi 0x104e character is [image]

These 2 characters are different in burmese. So i want to use this difference to detect the device used font is unicode or zawgyi.

My 2 tested devices:

1. ASUS Zenfone2 android 5.0 support unicode, but i installed the zawgyi font and change the display font to use zawgyi.
2. Nexus 5 android 6.1 support unicode.

I want to auto detect which fonts are supported in device. But i don't know how. 
Both devices show the uncodie 104e character "၎" in logcat. But in display screen, 2 devices show as expected one is unicode and one is in zawgyi font for 104e character as above attached image.

Is there a way to detect the display font?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Would just installing your own font in your apk and using it be sufficient?  Because I don't think there is an API to directly figure that out.

Comment: I think unicode would be the trend. Zawgyi is temporarily solving current situation. I know how to convert from unicode to zawgyi, there is a api to do that. So i don't want to put zawgyi font in my app. Also user can type in the text field and send to the database. So i would like to know the font they are using. The worst way is to let use choose which font they are using. I am looking for auto detection if possible.

Comment: @GabeSechan It has been a long time. But I would like to justify why just installing own font is not working. Some mobile vendors like Samsung override the own fonts with their customized fonts in Myanmar Specific version of devices. Pretty aweful.